# Wordpress: Very slow loading

Tags: ajax, wordpress, performance

I'm not a developer and our original developer doesn't know how to fix this, so I'm pretty desperate, hope you guys can help!

I have ran the website through different analysis:

Pingdom: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/dlRIXt/www.sanefitnesshk.com

Google Developers: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsanefitnesshk.com%2F&tab=desktop

I've already installed W3 Total Cache.

If you need any more information, please don't hesitate to ask as I don't even know where to start to fix this problem.

Thank you so much!

Comment: A quick look with the inspector shows me that a script is calling; `admin-ajax.php?action=jckqv_styles&ver=4.1.1` which takes around 9 seconds. I won't help out more since I don't work for free and I hope that you hire a developer to look into this for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "**defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering**".

Hope it helps you some extent.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably admin-ajax.php that does the most damage here. I can see it loading for 16 seconds, and no HTML rendering takes place before this.

You can see it with Chrome Developer Tools, but more clearly on webpagetest.org where you also can see the screenshots from different seconds.

More people having the same issue: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-ajaxphp-slow-server-response-time (If you have issues with Wordpress, you should create a new question.)

Comment: Couldn't find a solid solution from that forum, maybe i'm missing something?

Comment: No I didn't provide a simple solution for you. Do you have WooCommerce installed on the site? Start by upgrading Wordpress to the latest version, and all plugins if you havn't done so already.

Comment: Good answer here, for him it may have been a memory lack problem. https://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201220087-Woocommerce-Causes-Slow-admin-ajax-php-Load-Times?page=2#answer-200223649

Comment: Ok will try to updating everything to latest version, then try the other solution you suggested.

Thanks!